# C Shell Array Declaration Syntax, () vs. {}

Tags: shell, tcsh

In my C-shell script (tcsh specifically) I have been trying to declare an array with six values: x, nx, y, ny, z, nz. After some trial and error I discovered three different ways of declaring the array I want:

```
set arrname = ("x" "nx" "y" "ny" "z" "nz")
set arrname = (x,nx,y,ny,z,nz)
set arrname = {x,nx,y,ny,z,nz}
```

but the following line doesn't work:

```
set arrname = {"x" "nx" "y" "ny" "z" "nz"}
```

The above line produces the following error:

```
Missing }.
```

My question is what is different between () and {} that makes the fourth declaration I've listed not work?